# How do you split a dictionary string value in a list of dictionaries to add a new dictionary item?

Tags: python, dictionary, split

I have a list of dictionaries and in each list there is a key called text with a string value. To each dictionary I want to add a new item which is called first_word which is a split of the string of text to obtain the the code.

For example if I have:

```
alist =[{'id':1, 'text':'Dogs are great'},

{'id':2, 'text':'Cats are great'},

'id':3, 'text':'Fish are smelly'}]
```

I would want to add a new field called first_word:

```
alist =[{'id':1, 'text':'Dogs are great', 'first_word':'Dogs'},

{'id':2, 'text':'Cats are great', 'first_word':'Cats'},

'id':3, 'text':'Fish are smelly', 'first_word':'Fish'}]
```

The code which I have use to attempt this is below:

```
for ditem in alist:
    ditem['first_word'] = ditem['text'].split()[0]
```

however I am receiving the error:

> IndexError: list index out of range

How can I do this?

Comment: Is there any empty string value for `text`? The error is saying that the result of `split` is an empty list, hence `list[0]` invokes `IndexError`

Comment: Might there be dicts with an empty text in your list?

Comment: After fixing the typo in the example (`{` before `'id':3`), the loop works fine for me. Maybe your actual data has an empty string for `text`  somewhere.

Comment: wrap the `ditem['first_word'] = ditem['text'].split()[0]` in a `try`-`except IndexError` and add a `print(ditem)` on the except. You will know when you see it.

Comment: This is the output of your script (after the fix suggested by Muru:
[{'text': 'Dogs are great', 'id': 1, 'first_word': 'Dogs'}, {'text': 'Cats are great', 'id': 2, 'first_word': 'Cats'}, {'text': 'Fish are smelly', 'id': 3, 'first_word': 'Fish'}]

works as expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are probably dicts in your list whose 'text' is empty.

You can either sanitize your data or, if you want to ignore the empty texts and add an empty 'first_word' in this case, you could do:

```
for ditem in alist:
    ditem['first_word'] = ditem['text'].split()[0] if ditem['text'] else ''
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass an empty space character to the `split` method, like :

```
for ditem in alist:
    ditem['first_word'] = ditem['text'].split(' ', 1)[0]
```

Use the second argument to `.split()` to let the splitting stop early in case your strings are big.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works well apart from the typo. You missed a `{` before the third item.

Jupyter throws this

```
  File "<ipython-input-17-6aeaa3a052d5>", line 5
    'id':3, 'text':'Fish are smelly'}]
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Just amend it

```
alist =[{'id':1, 'text':'Dogs are great'},
{'id':2, 'text':'Cats are great'},
{'id':3, 'text':'Fish are smelly'}]

for ditem in alist:
    ditem['firstword']=ditem['text'].split()[0]

alist
```

**Output:**

```
[{'id': 1, 'text': 'Dogs are great', 'firstword': 'Dogs'},
 {'id': 2, 'text': 'Cats are great', 'firstword': 'Cats'},
 {'id': 3, 'text': 'Fish are smelly', 'firstword': 'Fish'}]
```

Comment: My actual code does not have this issue but I cannot get my code to work.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your dictionary. Look at line 3 if a list you're missing a curly brace.

Answer (score 0):

```
alist =[{'id':1, 'text':'Dogs are great'}, {'id':2, 'text':'Cats are great'}, {'id':3, 'text':'Fish are smelly'}]

def append_kv(dd):
    dd['first_word '] = ''
    return dd

alist = [append_kv(dd) for dd in alist]
```

Answer (score 0):

The particular `IndexError` you mentioned should only happen when you try to access a list element that doesn't exist. You have exactly one list access (the list output from `ditem['text'].split()`, and you're trying to access it's first element, so that list must be empty. This happens precisely when `ditem['text']` is empty, which gives us a quick fix: check to see if it's empty.

```
for ditem in alist:
    t = ditem['text']
    ditem['first_word'] = t.split()[0] if t else None
```

Answer (score -1):

Putting aside the missing brace, your code works on the input you show.

The only circumstances in which you'd get a `list index out of range` exception is if `text` is empty:

```
In [11]: for ditem in alist:
    ...:     ditem['first_word'] = ditem['text'].split()[0]
    ...:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

One way to fix this is by explicitly handling empty text:

```
In [12]: for ditem in alist:
    ...:     ditem['first_word'] = ditem['text'].split()[0] if ditem['text'] else ''
    ...:
    ...:
```